# News channels on ITunes Radio?

Tags: itunes-radio

On iTunes radio I have been unable to find any new news channels with the exception of public radio in every city.

Are there any other news stations on iTunes Radio?

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes you should have two options for listing to radio stations.

1) Internet stations (available in all Countries) - see the "[Internet](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12132)" tap under Music, where you should be able to find live stations with or without news.

2) Radio (not available in all Countries) - see the "[Radio](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5848)" tab under Music, this will only offer music streaming from a standard radio setup (possible to setup with your own music taste).

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes Radio or now Apple Music you can search for your local NPR station by call sign (not all are available). Or check out the main NPR station:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/station/npr-news-and-culture/idra.840950253